# REACT NATIVE - EXPO: I can't open a shared file with my app

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo, share

I have managed to share the state of my app through expo-sharing with success but when I try to configure my app to open that file I'm unable to find exactly how to do it. I'm building my project with expo and I have the prebuild done, so I can edit the androidManifest.xml, to add the intents but i tried everything that I found and nothing works. For now I'm trying only to make my app apear as an option in the list of apps to "Open with..." the shared file. But I cannot find a way anywhere, and the IA is pointing me wrong with this topic.

This is my AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <queries>
    <intent>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
      <data android:scheme="https"/>
    </intent>
  </queries>
  <application android:name=".MainApplication" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:allowBackup="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.ENABLED" android:value="false"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_SDK_VERSION" android:value="50.0.0"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATES_CHECK_ON_LAUNCH" android:value="ALWAYS"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATES_LAUNCH_WAIT_MS" android:value="0"/>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|uiMode" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" android:theme="@style/Theme.App.SplashScreen" android:exported="true" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="file" />
        <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.silencetm" />
        <data android:host="*" />
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="com.quim79.silenceTimer"/>
        <data android:scheme="exp+silencetimer"/>
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" android:exported="false"/>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

And this is the function that shares the state in a file:

```
  const handleSharePreset = async (item: SilenceTimerPreset) => {
    const fileName = `${item.title.replace(/\s/g, "_")}.silencetm`;
    const filePath = `${FileSystem.cacheDirectory}${fileName}`;
    await FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(filePath, JSON.stringify(item), {
      encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.UTF8,
    });

    await Sharing.shareAsync(filePath, {
      mimeType: "application/json",
      dialogTitle: "Share your Silence Timer Preset",
      UTI: "public.json",
    }).then(async () => {
      await FileSystem.deleteAsync(filePath).then(() => {
        console.log("File deleted!");
      });
    });
  };
```

Many thanks!